# import/require/use for perl modules

Tags: perl

I have 2 files perl files which have dependency on one another. 
The 1st file, A is a .pl file which multiple package/modules declared inside.
The 2nd file, B will try to access one of the many packages declared in file A. How can that be done?

Comment: How does A have a dependency on B?

Answer (score 3):

You may be familiar with how Java or a similar language finds an `import com.example.AppName` namespace by looking for the `com/example/AppName.java` file in the classpath. When you ask Perl for `use HTML::Template`, it likewise looks for `HTML/Template.pm` in the directories listed in `@INC`.

The difference is that a Perl file can have multiple packages.  When you say `use HTML::Template`, you'll be pulling in all packages listed in `HTML/Template.pm` (`use` automatically translates the `::` into the right directory separator for your system, and adds the `.pm`). If there happens to be a `HTML::Template::Extension` package in that file, then you can use that package without having to explicitly `use` it.  It's already loaded the complete file, and that's good enough.

If you know the exact file name relative where you'll be running the script, the easiest way to grab it is:

```
require 'path/to/file.pl';
```

Comment: In this case if my code in the .pm file is like the below
`package Template
...

package Extension
...`

Do I use HTML::Template or HTML::Extension to access either one of the module

Comment: Even if i have use `require 'path/to/file.pl'`
How do i access the many packages that i have defined in file.pl.
I have tried use Template; but it still looks for the Template.pm file

Comment: @superface - you don't `use Template` - you just use it: `Template->new()`.  But, really, you should follow convention, and put your packages into their own .pm files. It's just easier.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison between perl `@INC` and Java `classpath` was the key to me figuring out how to make use of a Perl file used as a local Perl module. Although `require` a file is more practical in the question's scenario, I will register how to achieve the same objective by importing a module, `use` keyword, after read @frezik answer.

The `@INC` array must be inspected to know where we can place our dependencies, this can be done with the one-liner Perl::

```
perl -e 'print $_ . "\n" for (@INC);'
```

For me, who doesn't use system-wide installation, it makes sense to inspect, the output of the above command is this for me:

```
/home/<my-username>/.asdf/installs/perl/5.38.2/lib/site_perl/5.38.2/x86_64-linux
/home/<my-username>/.asdf/installs/perl/5.38.2/lib/site_perl/5.38.2
/home/<my-username>/.asdf/installs/perl/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux
/home/<my-username>/.asdf/installs/perl/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2
```

A system-wide installation by Linux operating system package managers may point to some more common paths, such as `/usr/lib/perl5/...`

I choose some for my environment's directory that seem more generic, even if it's a simple test to learn these possibilities:

```
/home/<my-username>/.asdf/installs/perl/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2
```

In this path I created the structure file that represents the `Hello` module that belongs to a `Basic::HelloWorld` package, resulting in a `Hello.pm` file within a relative path `Basic/HelloWord` within the directory mentioned above.

`Hello.pm` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package Basic::HelloWorld

print "Hello, World.\n";
```

This way, some directory in the `@INC` array of my Perl environment has this module, as the file is in this absolute path:

```
/home/<my-username>/.asdf/installs/perl/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/Basic/HelloWord/Hello.pm
```

The file that should use this module can now reference this dependency,like this:

File `app.pl`, located in somewhere since that make use of the Perl installation that you put your local module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Basic::HelloWorld::Hello
```

You must ensure that the entry point has execute permission for the user who will execute, in this case the entry point `app.pl` file. Because modules themselves only need read permission for that user. So you can execute the `app.pl` file:

```
./app.pl
```

or

```
perl app.pl
```

The will produces the output below:

```
Hello, World.
```

Since the `app.pl` doesn't make anything beyond make use of `Hello` module, `Hello.pm` file, the output is generated due to print function in Hello module.

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare a module in each pl file that is using a function of the module.

Comment: Perl does not enforce a strict mapping that way. A file can contain multiple packages, and packages can even span multiple files.